# Cant change Django debug language

Tags: django

my django settings is already in Portuguese and English, as you can see below:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
]
```

But when there is an error in the code, it comes in german. I am located in Germany, I have a German laptop, but my Windows is also configured in English. I don't know where this german is coming from.

See an example here: https://ibb.co/cvhBcvd

PLEASE, I don't need help with the error, I just would like to have all my errors in English.

Thank you gurus.

Comment: Not suggesting this as a long term solution, but just trying to pin down the source of what's going on. What happens if you set `USE_I18N=False`? I think that because you have translation turned on, and you're located in Germany, Django thinks it should show you the German version of its pages.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but there is no accepted answer so here's how I solved the problem. Maybe this helps someone else.

First of all, it's not a Django translation issue. I think this is evident by the fact that all other logging messages are in English. In this situation, Django is merely relaying an error message from the database itself, therefore, the language issue is with the database.

I use PostgreSQL, so to solve the problem all I did was delete the locale folder within the PostgreSQL installation:

PostgreSQL\14\share\locale\

Not sure why Postgres insisted on translating to German when my system language is in English but doing this fixed my Django problem. Everything back to English now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
language = get_language_info('pt-br')
translation.activate(language)
```

I THINK (and this could be completely wrong) it is trying to use i18n which thinks German is the language of the machine so since it is DEBUG info it is trying to give it to you in a useful language (in production you wouldn't have DEBUG=True)